# How many seconds does afterburn damage last?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When an enemy is hit with a fire enchanted weapon they catch on fire and take additional damage over time.

How long does that last?

Comment: http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Fire_Damage Info on fire damage here. But no reference to how long it lasts.

Comment: Related - http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37292/how-much-damage-does-after-burn-do

Answer (score 2):

According to the creation kit, the taper duration (how long the spell lasts after it's cast) for each of the fire spells is:

- **Flames:** .1 Seconds
- **Firebolt:** 1 Second
- **Fireball:** 2 Seconds
- **Incinerate:** 1 Second
- **Fire Storm:** 4 Seconds

Testing on a few giants, this seems about right.  Flames dies out almost immediately.  Firebolt and Incinerate last the same length, Fireball and Fire Storm last longer.

The non-direct spells list taper durations of:

- **Fire Rune:** 1 second spell duration, 1 second taper
- **Flame Cloak:** 60 Second duration (time on self), 2 second taper
- **Wall of Flame:** 1 second spell duration, 2 second taper

Answer (score -1):

The afterburn damage effect lasts for 7-9 seconds, but it depends on the spell/how much damage the enchantment does.

Comment: How do you know that? Where did you find this information?

Comment: Personal experience.

Comment: My personal experience is that afterburn lasts about 3 seconds... Some specific information in this area would be useful.